# Get Details of an public IP in azure

Tags: azure

Given a public IP and knowing that this IP is hosted in Azure, is there a way to find out details of the ownership of the IP, like mail id of the team which owns the IP, or subscription id under which the IP belongs? Can any Geneva action give this info or querying a kusto table? This IP can belong to a DNS Server, a Service, etc.

Comment: A court order (lawsuit or law enforcement actions) would likely be the main way.

Answer (score 5):

No, the only information you can get from an IP will be the owner, which will be Microsoft. Revealing any other data would be a significant breach of privacy.